# read text from camera using vision framework ios

Tags: vision

I want to programmatically read numbers on a page using mobile's camera instead from image, just like barcode scanning. I know that we can read or scan barcode but is there any way to read numbers using same strategy.

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried text detection with vision framework but i only gives a frame which contain words but did not give any string